# Optimal way of creating a large table from a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata, database-optimization

I've got a pretty complex select query, but it's otherwise optimized based on the `EXPLAIN`. I want to create a concrete table from the results of this select. But the challenge is that this is a large table that consists of 70 million records. Two ways of creating this new table, from what I know, would be to do a Create Table As Select (CTAS), or creating the table first and then doing an `INSERT INTO`.

CTAS seems to be the most performant way to go, but I also wonder about doing this all in one shot for 70 million records. I normally would have thought about doing this in chunks, but I'm not sure if it's possible with CTAS, considering the table is being created at that point. And then the `INSERT INTO` option has the overhead of all the inserts.

I'd like to know if anyone has done something like this before, or if they had any other pointers for accomplishing this.

Comment: Create table skeleton with the data (CREATE TABLE .. SELECT, but no indices/constraints in the structure) then adjust the structure with according ALTERR TABLE.

Comment: If you're doing it in chunks, the easiest way is with `INSERT INTO AS SELECT`

Comment: I don't think there's any significant difference in overhead between CTAS and IIAS. Just do it as Akina suggests -- don't add the indexes until after everything is inserted.

Comment: I'm so accustomed to queries running relatively quickly, but I think in reality, there are just cases where queries will take a long time no matter what we do. And this is my first time really attempting something with a table this large.

Comment: Inserting 70 million rows will take some time no matter what. The question is... are you OK with that delay? Is it OK to divide in chunks?

Comment: Yeah, it would be fine to divide into chunks.

Comment: This is a one-time task, correct?  What is the downside of the task taking minutes?

Comment: You haven't actually said where these 70 million rows are coming from or if they are a clone of an existing table, or harvested from many tables.